# Comments lose indentation in vim when in insert mode

Tags: vim, python

I'm getting some annoying behavior in Vim. If I'm on a line that's indented (4-spaces), and I hit `o` to open a new line, it puts me in insert mode with my cursor properly on the indented lines, but if I type a `#`, it jumps back to the leftmost column.

I downloaded someone else's setup and have made a few mods, but I can't seem to figure out the cause.

Here's my vimrc:
http://pastebin.com/9mGWr8Qf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior depends on the value of `formatoptions`. The value returned by `:set fo` should contain the letters `r` and `o` for Vim to do what you expect (see `:h fo-table`).

Do `:verbose set fo` to see where it was last defined.

Oh! And using someone else's config is a very bad idea.

Comment: Well the guy who wrote the vimrc set it up as a github repo and actually wrote a blog about it. http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide

Comment: Since my vimrc does not have format options set anywhere, I suppose that means that it's default? `:verbose set fo` tells me `formatoptions=tcq Last set from ~/.vimrc` but I don't have anything referencing formatoptions in my vimrc

Comment: Yes that's vim's awkward and unhelpful way to say that it's the default value. Just set it explicitely to whatever you need.

Comment: Great, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

There was a post about this on stackoverflow.
But this only works if you also "set cindent"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469463/vim-c-back-indent-with

```
:set cindent
:set cinkeys-=0#
```

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: Plus I'm in Python not C

Comment: just making sure, lines 199 and 200 are your comments right? they don't work? Maybe i'll copy this vimrc and play around with it and see what I can do. when I did the above it worked for me, I apologize.

Comment: Line 199 was a comment describing 200, I initially thought that 200 was the cause of the problem so I commented it out, but it did not help. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @BenMordecai the cinkeys does work but you ALSO need to "set cindent"  I know you are not coding in C, but it works.